# ¿Como puedo ver desde el cmd si el puerto 8080 esta abierto?

Tags: windows, apache, cmd, puertos

¿Como puedo saber si el puerto 8080 esta abierto? Estoy utilizando un servidor con Windows

Comment: Puedes usar el comando netstat

Comment: TCP    127.0.0.1:4200         DESKTOP-O0QVBEM:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4200         DESKTOP-O0QVBEM:51201  ESTABLISHED

Comment: a que se refiere el que dice ESTABLISHED ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use el siguiente comando:

```
netstat -an | find ":8080"
```

O también puede probar `findstr`

```
netstat -na | findstr "8080"
```

para verificar si el puerto 8080 está abierto.

> Para reducir los resultados. También puede filtrar por `LISTENING`, `ESTABLISHED`, `TCP`. Sin embargo, es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

**Nota:** Al ejecutar el comando si no muestra Nada significa que el puerto NO está siendo escuchado (no está en uso)

Answer (score 0):

En Windows ejecutas cmd y escriber netstat -an

Comment: Jorge, agrega más información a tu pregunta el sistema la reporto como  de "baja calidad", el formato que tiene actualmente podría ser de un comentario. Te sugiero modificar tu respuesta, revisa [answer], saludos!